# Cannot open Popup In Mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to use jQuery Dialog popup, when I first load the site. But it is not opening currently.

Here is the Code:

_Layout:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            alert("hi")
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
              height:140,modal:true
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Index View:-

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="basic Title Modal">
    <p>This is A Test Modal</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly check wether your Jquery file is Included or not.

Comment: Agreed, you should get used to using the JavaScript debugger on your browser too, the javascript you've currently written is broken (if it's the same one you're using on the site) beacuse you're not terminating the lines with ';' so it will just stop executing.

Comment: @Foash this is working in fiddle so your problem is most probably caused from the included scripts in the `<head>`. First of all, delete all `scripts` from the head except the one with the `dialog function` and include only `jquery-1.8*` and `jquery-ui-1.8.24`. When you verify that it works like that start to include other scripts and see when things go wrong. I'm pretty sure that `~/bundles/jquery` is loading `jquery-ui` for you and my guess is - the second attempt to include it manually is breaking things.

Comment: Try it simply as `$("#dialog-modal").dialog();` to confirm its working. I suspect the issue is `modal:true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you are facing is because you are rendering the script in the body before loading the jquery

you have 2 solutions for this case

1- load the jquery in the header

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="dialog" title="basic Title Modal">
    <p>This is A Test Modal</p>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
</script>
```

2- add you script to the section "scripts"

example:
_layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="dialog" title="basic Title Modal">
    <p>This is A Test Modal</p>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the jquery js files are being loaded OK, since you have both of these:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
```

I would check that the layout page is loading the bundles OK by checking both layout.cs and the bundles config. Also ensure it is the correct version of jquery.

As a side note, better to use layout.cshtml if you can and load the scripts that way rather than hardcoding the version number - e.g.

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

then in the bundle.config

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
   "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to load it once the DOM is ready you need to wrap it inside a document ready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            alert("hi");
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
              height:140,modal:true
            });
});
```

I'm not sure if you need both jQuery and jQueryUI scripts for this, also `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` I'm not sure what it does but if it does load scripts, it's best to not have them piling up inside the body tag.

Comment: `$(function()` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready()`. [Refer docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). And `@RenderSection()` is a placeholder for rendering the scripts from the view and its exactly the right place for them (immediately before the closing `</body>` tag)